# Не убирается значение checked у чекбокса

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!
Есть код

```
$('.all-checkbox').on('click', function() {
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
    $('.popup-selectes').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', false).trigger('refresh');
} else {
    $('.popup-selectes').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', true).trigger('refresh');
}
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я использую для стилизации плагин FormStyler. Но, думаю, проблема не в нем. Когда я нажимаю на один главный чекбокс, все другие становятся активные. Я делаю проверку, что если главный чекбокс активный, то при клике на него он перестанет быть активным и другие чекбоксы также должны убрать checked. В итоге как раз не работает удаление checked.
[Вот ссылка. В открытом попапе "Выбрать все"](http://verstka.test30.ru/test/test2)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Перепутали логику в if/else. Должно быть наоборот.

2) У вас чекбокс имеет класс all-checkbox и такой же класс имеет div в котором находится чекбокс, что вызывает двойной клик и путаницу.

```js
$('.all-checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     $('.popup-selectes').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', true).trigger('refresh');
    } else {
     $('.popup-selectes').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', false).trigger('refresh');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup-parametrs">
      <div class="popup-select-all">
        <label class="label">
          <div class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox all-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="popup-selectes">
        <div class="left">
          <label class="label">
            <div class="checkbox checked"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ></div>
          </label>
          <label class="label">
            <div class="checkbox checked"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ></div>
          </label>
          <label class="label">
            <div class="checkbox checked"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ></div>
          </label>
          <label class="label">
            <div class="checkbox checked"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, так плагин отрабатывает.. С одинаковыми классами..В любом случае спасибо :) Понял в чем ошибка благодаря вам :)